# Can I leave Match Chat?

Tags: overwatch

Is it possible leave Match Chat?  I'm only interested in using voice/text with my own team.  I glanced at the options menu, but I didn't see anything obvious.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. During a match, press P to bring up channel settings. Click on the filled speech bubble next to "Match" to remove yourself from match chat. You can also remove yourself from team chat or voice chat in a similar fashion.

The settings will persist across matches, so you don't have to do this every time.

Comment: And that explains it.  I thought that menu only controlled voice options.  Thanks!

Comment: I will note this isn't permanent.  You have to do this once each time when you start Overwatch, but it will persist the entire time you play as the answer states.

Answer (score 2):

You can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to hide the chat. It also persists for the entire session.

To show the chat again either press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> again or Enter.